# Error while making a login form for a VB.NET project

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to make a login form for a basic VB.NET project, and this is the error I get for writing anything in the password area:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'password'

My code:

```
Dim cnct As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\...")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from LOGin where username='" + user.Text + " And password='" + pass.Text + "", cnct)

Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
sda.Fill(dt)

If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
    MessageBox.Show("connction reussi")
    Dim form As New mainForm
    form.Show()
    Me.Close()
Else
    MsgBox("Votre nom d'utilisateur ou votre mot de passe est incorrecte", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    user.Text = ""
    pass.Text = ""
    user.Focus()
End If
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries. And don't store clear text passwords, hash them.

Comment: Your missing an ' after the password.  Should read "And password = '" + pass.Text + "'", cnct).  But as sticky has said, use parameters at least and encrypt your password in the DB

Comment: Thank you, the problem was a missing  '   as u said Hursey, it is my first time working with both sql and vb.net next thing i m gonna do is to learn how to use parameterized queries and encrypt my passwords.

Comment: @A.hilmi, if the password is used only for authentication, it would be better so store only the password hash (salted) to validate against the value provided. That way, passwords can't be accessed if data are compromised.

Comment: For future reference, if an error message tells you that there's a syntax error in your SQL code, the very first thing you should do is actually look at that SQL code. If you had done that then you'd have seen quite easily that there was a missing quote. This is also an example of why you should avoid string concatenation. It makes your code harder to read and thus more error-prone. Using `String.Format` or string interpolation makes code easier to read and thus less error-prone. Of course, using parameters with SQL avoids even more problems.

Comment: if it's winforms and you are attached to an AD...consider if you even need a "username/password" or can instead of active directory and hook your username to a windows domain/username, so that the login is not needed at all.  Always step back before considering writing your own authentication/authorization scheme.